# Cannot resolve symbol "FragmentActivity"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an issue with FragmentActivity class
when i import the package :

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

when i put it in the code import FragmentActivity be red and Android dtudio says Cannot resolve symbol i have tried all the solution in prev. similar topics on stackoverflow and other websites but the error is still in the code 
[image]

i updated support-v4 and gradle version and my sdk is up to date
thanks and goodbye :D

android gradle:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
android {
    signingConfigs {
        CirclePong {
            keyAlias 'madtriangle'
            keyPassword 'piratamenu94'
            storeFile file('/Users/ManuGil/Documents/LibGDX/apk/CirclePong/circlepong.jks')
            storePassword 'piratamenu94'
        }

    }
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    compileSdkVersion 25
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            jniLibs.srcDir new File(buildDir, 'lib')
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
/*
// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}
*/
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'circlepong.android/com.madtriangle.circlepong.AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}
// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
}
```

Basegameutile gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
        }
```

Comment: Are you using Any ToolBar . FragmentActivity can not resolve ToolBar.

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'` add it to your dependencies then sync project

Comment: @PhanVanLinh It's in v4 support library not v7 please see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)

Comment: @AtefHares v7 contains v4

Comment: yes you are right, I did not know that before, I thought they are separated, Thanks

Comment: You need to clean, build and then sync the gradle

Comment: i edited my topic and added gradle 
@PhanVanLinh

Comment: i edited my topic and added gradle
@AtefHares

Comment: Have you Sync Project with Gradle Files with help of button in the toolbar? Or try Build->Clean Project Or Build->Rebuild Project

Comment: Yea i made this things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing this section from `Basegameutile gradle`

```
 configurations {
       all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
 }
```

It prevents the inclusion of the support library.

This section is used when there is a dependency conflict between 2 or more modules because both of them include the support library .

To prevent one of them from including the same dependency use this section.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Mohammad :)
It works for me :) -- Dat made my day :)

Answer (score 10):

Try **import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity** if you are using **androidx** in your project. It's work for me

Comment: Welcome to SO. What makes you think they are using `androidx`?